# Reshaping DataFrame in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python pandas data frame like this

```
col1 col2 col3  
s1   a    2  
s1   b    1  
s1   c    3  
s2   d    2  
s2   e    5  
s2   f    1  
s3   a    2
```

I want to reshape it like this

```
col1  col2_appended col3_sum  
s1    a,b,c         6  
s2    d,e,f         8     
s3    a             2
```

First column has distinct values from col1, the second column has values of col2 concatenated with commas and the 3rd column has sum of col3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).agg({'col2': ','.join, 'col3': sum})

    col1    col2    col3
0   s1      a,b,c   6
1   s2      d,e,f   8
2   s3      a       2
```